# Get method nothing shows up

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm on my localhost and when i start the server it shows nothing. When i go to localhost:8080/register it should show "asdasd" (as you can see in the code) but it doesnt work.
Can you guys help me out? Thank you very much!

```
const U2F = require("u2f");
const Express = require("express");
const BodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Cors = require("cors");
const HTTP = require("http");
const FS = require("fs");
const session = require("express-session");

const APP_ID = "http://localhost:8080/";

var app = Express();

app.use(session({ secret: "test", cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60000 }, saveUninitialized: true, resave: true }));
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(Cors({ origin: [APP_ID], credentials: true }));

var user;

app.get("/", (request, response, next) => {
    response.end("Hello Test");
});

app.get("/register", (request, response, next) => {
    console.log("asdasd");
});

app.post("/register", (request, response, next) => {});

app.get("/login", (request, response, next) => { });

app.post("/login", (request, response, next) => { });

HTTP.createServer(function (request, response){
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass app(returned by express) inside HTTP.createServer

HTTP.createServer(app).listen(8080);

Answer (score 1):

1) for a start your are logging "asdasd" to the console and not responding to the request made at the "/register" endpoint, just modify your code to the one below.

```
app.get("/register", (request, response, next) => {
        response.end("asdasd");
    });
```

2) you have not actually created a server for app , http.createserver is not tied to app

modify your code to the below

```
const server = HTTP.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080,()=>console.log("server is listening on port 8080")
```

Comment: Lol, I think so far. But even that is not possible.